# Match negative and positive decimals?

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm trying to match positive and negative numbers inbetween two tags using regex, the positive numbers return fine but the negative ones do not match. I am using:

```
string value8 = (",\"lng\":\"(([^\"\\\\]|-\\\\.)*)\",");
Match[] lng = Regex.Matches(Text, value8)
```

to match against

```
"lng":"-104.845275878905880"
```

or similar, it can be positive or negative. When positive it matches the number but when negative, there are no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your regex looks a little more complex than it needs to be. You should be able to use something like this:

```
"\"lng\":\\\"(-?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*)\\\""
```

Incidentally, I removed the comma at the beginning of your expression, as that would prevent this pattern from matching your sample data.

Comment: ahh sorry about that the comma is supposed to be there although it is matching 0.00000000000000 for some odd reason.

Comment: @user556396: Does this new pattern solve your issue if you add the comma?